# AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I'm trying to visualize the LDA Topics using the **pyLDAvis** library

I'll be using  `sklearn.decomposition's` LatentDirichletAllocation`

My sklearn's version: 1.2.2

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'
```

This is a small part of my code:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation as LDA

%matplotlib inline
import pyLDAvis.sklearn

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['cons']).todense()
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
panel = pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda, vectors, vectorizer, mds='tsne')
pyLDAvis.display(panel)
```

Answer (score 0):

TfidfVectorizer parameters are present in:

https://scikit-learn.org/1.2/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

The parameter you are asking is not vectorizer.get_feauture_names but the documentation states that the correct parameter is vectorizer.get_feature_names_out([inputs])